# Getting started with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

### Schema Root

```
<xs:schema jxb:version="1.0"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
http://www.nubean.com/schemas/schema.xsd" >
<xs:element name="UsOrCanadaAddress" >
```

### JAXB Binding XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema" schemaLocation="address.xsd" >
<jxb:schemaBindings>
<jxb:package name="com.apress.jaxb1.example" ></jxb:package>
</jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I am beginning with JAXB and these are the two tags I came across in the books.
I have a few basic questions regarding the various parts of the two tags. Here they go:

*Question 1:*

```
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
```

Does this attribute has to have the exact same value ?

*Question 2:*

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    http://www.nubean.com/schemas/schema.xsd"
```

This attribute, in the schema.. in the schema ??? I mean, I can understand that attribute in an XML document pointing to an XML schema but this ? What does it do if not trigger a schema-ception ?
Also, the namespace-location pair. In an XML document it would point to a physical location. Here, does it have to point to a physical location ?

*Question 3:*
The word *binding*. In my head I understand that as `settings` that you can change in mobile or computer apps. They have default values which you can change. In the above binding document, they have changed the package *setting*. Now, assuming that I do not want to keep the document in no package, I should leave that as it is ?
I will not need to write that binding XML document ?

*Question 4:*
In the JAXB binding document `schemaLocation="address.xsd"` points to the schema location. Now  that is the physical location. What if my schema was packed with a JAR file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1 - Does this attribute has to have the exact same value ?

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation expects the elements the elements in the binding file to be qualified with the `"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"` namespace.  It does not depend on a particular prefix being used.

---

> Question 2 - This attribute, in the schema.. in the schema ???

Since the XML schema is an XML document I guess doing this is ok, but I have never done this in an XML schema myself.

---

> Question 3 - The word binding.

I have a kind of love/hate relationship with the word "binding".  It has come to be assocated with converting objects to/from data formats that aren't necessarily persistent (i.e. XML, JSON, etc).

---

> Question 4 - In the JAXB binding document schemaLocation="address.xsd"
>   points to the schema location.

I do not believe that the `schemaLocation` is required in the bindings file.

---

Since you are just getting started with JAXB you may not want to get hung up on the binding document.  It's only needed when you need to customize the classes generated from an XML schema.  Below is an example where it is not needed:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

What I find is the more interesting use case is staring from objects.  Below is an example you may find useful:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: What you are simply implying is that the use case I am referring to is unnecessarily complex ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild - Potentially :).  I cover a lot of JAXB topics on my Java XML and JSON Binding blog (http://blog.bdoughan.com/) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Do you have like `for dunce` section ? I am going to need that :)

Comment: @LittleChild - If there is a topic you would like to see covered feel free to send me a message:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html

Comment: You may wanna have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579050/how-do-i-efficiently-manage-the-various-conversion-tasks

Comment: @LittleChild - I just posted an answer to the question you linked to in your comment:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16591247/383861