# How do I efficiently manage the various conversion tasks?

Tags: java, dom, xpath, video-processing

I am making a video converter as a holiday project. I was planning on using an XML file to represent the pending tasks so the user can save the tasks. here is what it will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<task-list>
    <task>
        <input-location> </input-location>
        <output-location> </output-location>
        <bit-rate> </bit-rate>
        <output-width> </output-width>
        <output-height> </output-height>
        <target-device> </target-device>
    </task>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</task-list>
```

Now, here is what I have in mind:
1. Parse this to a `org.w3c.dom.Document`
2. Use XPath to get a `NodeList` which will contain all `<task>` and it's children.
3. Create a `Vector<Task>` where `Task` is a custom class. Each `Task` object will contain a `org.w3c.dom.Node`
4. Use XPath in context of the `Node` associated with each `Task` object to obtain relevant information.

But here is a problem: **How do I mutate the `Node` ?** Maybe the user wants to change the output location. I will have to make the changes to the concerned `Task` object's `Node` , the `org.w3c.dom.Document` (which also holds a copy of the Node from the saved file) and save it to the file (for consistency the next time the converter is run).
This would get very cumbersome using XPath. XPath is good for data 'recovery' but not for changing, I presume.

### public class Task

```
public class Task{
    Node taskInfo;
    JProgressBar progressBar; // Visual feedback to the user
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    // getters and setters
}
```

I can make getters work using XPath. Setters are the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding)

Comment: @Craig can it be used to make a `Vector<Task>` directly???

Comment: JAXB uses annotations to bind xml data directly to java objects. You will create the java classes, JAXB will turn them into xml and back again [JAXB Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html) has a good beginners guide. I think JAXB will make your life a lot easier

Comment: @Craig he does show very simply how to do it but does not provide the xml file.

Comment: If you run the code provided, the xml file will be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following with any [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation.  An implementation is included in the JDK/JRE starting with Java SE 6:

**JAVA MODEL**

**TaskList**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="task-list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TaskList {

    @XmlElement(name="task")
    private List<Task> tasks;

}
```

**Task**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Task {

    @XmlElement(name="input-location")
    private String inputLocation;

    @XmlElement(name="output-location")
    private String outputLocation;

    @XmlElement(name="bit-rate")
    private int bitRate;

    @XmlElement(name="output-width")
    private int outputWidth;

    @XmlElement(name="output-height")
    private int outputHeight;

    @XmlElement(name="target-device")
    private String targetDevice;

}
```

**DEMO CODE**

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TaskList.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum16579050/input.xml");
        TaskList taskList = (TaskList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(taskList, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<task-list>
    <task>
        <input-location>foo input</input-location>
        <output-location>foo output</output-location>
        <bit-rate>1</bit-rate>
        <output-width>2</output-width>
        <output-height>3</output-height>
        <target-device>foo</target-device>
    </task>
    <task>
        <input-location>bar input</input-location>
        <output-location>bar output</output-location>
        <bit-rate>4</bit-rate>
        <output-width>5</output-width>
        <output-height>6</output-height>
        <target-device>bar</target-device>
    </task>
</task-list>
```

Comment: can I use a `Vector<Task>` here: `private List<Task> tasks`;

Comment: @LittleChild - Yes you can use `Vector<Task>` if you want to.  I wouldn't recommend using `Vector` though unless you specifically need a synchronized `List`.

Answer (score 1):

1. take a look at [Apache Digester](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/)
2. create a schema for your XML and process that schema into classes (which will be JAXB annotated), and then XML will become java objects much more easily (JAXB documentation will tell everything)